# QUERY and IF function

Tags: sql, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a long, long query function into a if function from three cells (below is a simple version with two cells):

```
=IF(B2="All";Query(Sheet!1:100000;"select B,C,F"); Query(Sheet!1:100000;"select B,C,F where C contains """&B2&""" and B contains """&D2&"""  ")
```

B2 and D2 are the cells where I have item lists that fill my query

Now I want: insert a blank value at the start of the query. I can use:

```
if (isblank(B2);iferror(1/0)
```

but doesn't go with two or more cells.

```
=if (isblank(B2);iferror(1/0), if(isblank(D2);iferror(1/0),,IF(B2="All";Query(Sheet1!1:100000;"select B,C,F"); Query(Sheet1!1:100000;"select B,C,F, where C contains """&B2&""" and B contains """&D2&""" "))))
```

More, I want learn to use different conditions (with OR and AND).

Can you help me?

Comment: Why don't you share a doc with us?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want either but guess it might be:

```
=IF(or(ISBLANK(B2),isblank(D2)),iferror(1/0),if(B2="All",Query(Sheet4!1:100000,"select B,C,F"), Query(Sheet4!1:100000,"select B,C,F where C contains """&B2&""" and B contains """&D2&""" ",C9)))
```